# Execute Perl script on a remote server through SSH with PHP WebPage

Tags: php, perl, remote-server

I need to launch a Perl script on server B from server A with a PHP WebPage through SSH.

My command looks like:

```
$cmd_string="ssh user@serverB 'perl path/to/script.pl param1 param2'";
```

I tried both inside PHP script but nothing happen:

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd_string, $outputfile, $pidfile));
exec($cmd_string, $output);
```

Running this command through terminal works just well.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what error / return value do you get?

Comment: Are you able to login into the server with php?

Comment: SSH connection is automatized for user "user" to server B.
But in error.log I get: 
`Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.`
It looks as if process is ran by 'www-data' instead of 'user'??

Comment: Don't you mean `&&` just before the `echo`?  One `&` would throw the command into the background and run the `echo` independently: I guess it would report if it could launch the first program, but not the first program's status.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation - use [phpseclib, a PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('perl path/to/script.pl param1 param2');
?>
```

exec() is often disabled on hosts for security reasons.